# Unable to connect to OIM server. [An error occurred while trying to notify server that a new login session has been created.]

Tags: api, exception, client, oim

I am trying to connect to the OIM server using oimclient.jar. When I try to login using below code. I'm getting error:  An error occurred while trying to notify server that a new login session has been created.
code:
    configEnv.put(OIMClient.JAVA_NAMING_FACTORY_INITIAL,

```
  OIMClientConnectorConstants.JAVA_NAMING_FACTORY_INITIAL);

  configEnv.put(OIMClient.JAVA_NAMING_PROVIDER_URL,

  OIMClientConnectorConstants.JAVA_NAMING_PROVIDER_URL);

  oimClient = new OIMClient(configEnv);


  List response = oimClient.login(

  OIMClientConnectorConstants.OIM_USERNAME,

  OIMClientConnectorConstants.OIM_PASSWORD);

  connector.setOimClient(oimClient);
```

Error:

```
Apr 18, 2014 10:03:30 AM oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient loginSessionCreated

SEVERE: An error occurred while trying to notify server that a new login session has been created.

oracle.iam.platform.utils.NoSuchServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

  at oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient.getServiceDelegate(OIMClient.java:278)

  at oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient.getService(OIMClient.java:255)

  at oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient.loginSessionCreated(OIMClient.java:290)

  at oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient.login(OIMClient.java:214)

  at oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient.login(OIMClient.java:183)

  at com.cred.service.oim.OIMClientConnector.getInstance(OIMClientConnector.java:92)

  at com.cred.data.UserProfileDataService.fecthCompleteUserProfile(UserProfileDataService.java:28)

  at com.cred.rest.UserProfileRestService.fecthCompleteUserProfile(UserProfileRestService.java:62)

  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)

  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)

  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)

  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)

  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)

  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)

  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)

  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)

  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)

  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)

  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

  at oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient.getServiceDelegate(OIMClient.java:274)

  ... 40 more

Caused by: oracle.iam.platform.utils.NoSuchServiceException: javax.naming.AuthenticationException [Root exception is java.lang.SecurityException: User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated.]

  at oracle.iam.platformservice.api.ClientLoginSessionServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)

  ... 45 more

Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException [Root exception is java.lang.SecurityException: User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated.]

  at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:42)

  at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:792)

  at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.pushSubject(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:686)

  at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.newContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:471)

  at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:376)

  at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)

  at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)

  at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)

  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)

  at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)

  at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)

  at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)

  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.createInitialContext(JndiTemplate.java:137)

  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.getContext(JndiTemplate.java:104)

  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:86)

  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:153)

  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)

  ... 46 more

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated.

  at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl.authenticate(RMIBootServiceImpl.java:116)

  at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)

  at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)

  at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)

  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)

  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)

  at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)

  at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)

  ... 2 more
```

Comment: Based on the exception thrown, user `weblogic` can't be authenticated. Let me ask you, which line of your code causes exception: the one with `login` or the next one?

Comment: after login it is throwing exception login is getting succeeded

Comment: Is the password a character array or a string? try OIM_PASSWORD.toCharArray()

Comment: its character array only